# Wordpress Filter Products by Tag and Category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a small wordpress hobby project and I have run into a bit of a snag. I have implemented WooCommerce and am using Category and Tags for my data.

I have some entries which I know relate so for an example, the data would model as follows:

Car #1:
Category => Sedan
Tag => Volvo

Car #2:
Category => Sedan
Tag => Volvo

Car #3:
Category => Sedan
Tag => BMW

I am trying to filter these WooCommerce products to ensure that both tag and category match so in this instance, Car #1 is related to Car #2 and Car #3 is an Orphan.

The current query that is being generated when getting related products is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p   
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON ( pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key='_visibility' )  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id) 

INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON(tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)  
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)  
WHERE (( tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.term_id IN ( 14 ))) 
OR  (( tt.taxonomy = 'product_tag' AND t.term_id IN ( 44) ));
```

The query gives me the correct result when I use OR however with more data I then get results which only satisfy one criteria which doesn't work well. I think the issue is that it is only fetching one taxonomy row per post so when I use AND (in where conditions) instead of OR in the query above, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a solution to this or has experiencing a similiar issue? Alternatively is there a better way that I should structure the products?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WP_Query` with `tax_query` and define an `AND` relation there to get the correct query. For example in your case something like this might work;

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'volvo' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'sedan' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For more information see the [WordPress Codex on WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). Good luck!